# jQuery - Find and replace text, after body was loaded

Tags: jquery, find, replace

I received some amazing help from others, concerning finding and replacing text with jquery.

The code below will find the word: "Subject:" and replace it with "Name:"

```
$("*").each(function () { 
   if ($(this).children().length == 0) { 
      $(this).text($(this).text().replace('Subject:','Name:')); 
   } 
});
```

And this works wonderfully.

The only thing I'm running into issues with is replacing text that is loaded after the page loads.

I do have some javascript functions that are displaying data from the server, but only after the page has loaded all elements. For example, a user selects a value from a dropdown that initiates an event to load a list of products from the database.

I format some of those products like this:

Granny Smith Apples 
Price: x.xx per pound 
Nutritional facts....

I will only want to find a replace the word "Price:", and possibly replace it with "Cost:".

But as I mentioned, that data has not been loaded yet. And only displays after the user selects "Granny Smith Apples" from the dropdown menu.

Is this a limit I have to live with?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try attaching an event to the [`ajaxStop` event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) as well as on load:

```
function replaceText() {
    var jthis = $(this);
    $("*").each(function() { 
        if(jthis.children().length==0) { 
            jthis.text(jthis.text().replace('Subject:', 'Name:')); 
        } 
    });
}
$(document).ready(replaceText);
$("html").ajaxStop(replaceText);
```

Comment: Where do I add this snippet? functions.php, my theme file? Sorry for the noobie question.

Answer (score 1):

Call your function from the `$(document).ready()` callback like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { replace_stuff(); } );
```

Comment: I'm already doing that, and still not affecting data loaded after the page has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The function below works perfectly for me:

```
function replaceText(selector, text, newText, flags) {
  var matcher = new RegExp(text, flags);
  $(selector).each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.children().length)
       $this.text($this.text().replace(matcher, newText));
  });
}
```

Here's a usage example:

```
function replaceAllText() {
  replaceText('*', 'Subject:', 'Name:', 'igm');
}

$(document).ready(replaceAllText);
$('html').ajaxStop(replaceAllText);
```