# How To Append <a></a> Tags To Specific Words In An Element With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The tricky part is not selecting the elements here, but just selecting the text within. The only true jQuery that will give you back text contents is .contents(). So I'm getting the contents of every element not he page, and I want to pick out a word, such as "hashtag". Then append  to it.

What am I doing wrong here:

```
<html>
<p>
The word hashtag is in this sentence.
</p>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('*')
        .contents()
        .filter(function(){
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        })
        .filter(function(){
            return this.nodeValue.indexOf('hashtag') != -1;
        })
        .each(function(){
            alert("It works!")
        });
});
```

`$('*')` grabs every element

`.contents()` grabs the contents of every element

`.filter(function(){ return this.noteType === 3;` refines it down to the text contents of elements. (#3 node type is text)

`return this.nodeValue.indexOf('hashtag')` should grab the word "hashtag". Not sure if this is working.

`!= -1;` should prevent it from grabbing every single element in the HTML. Not sure about that one.

Why doesn't it work? I know I have anything appending  tags yet, but  can I select the word "hashtag" thanks!

Comment: One question please. **WHY**?

Comment: @gdoron Maybe the OP wants to automatically create a link to a Google search for names that are not in the word dictionary? Just a wild guess.

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? I created a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yr7at/

Comment: I know the alert says it works. That's my mistake. Thanks for the fiddle.

As for why... I'm working on a project that involves conversion of text to links sort of what the second comment said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this for the whole page you can work on the HTML of the `body` element:

```
$(function() {
    var regExp = new RegExp("\\b(" + "hashtag" + ")\\b", "gm");
    var html = $('body').html();
    $('body').html(html.replace(regExp, "<a href='#'>$1</a>"));
});
```

Keep in mind that this may be slow if your page is large. Also, all elements will be rewritten and thus loose their event handlers etc.

If you don't want this or want to restrict the replacement to certain elements, you can select and iterate over them:

```
$(function() {
    var regExp = new RegExp("\\b(" + "hashtag" + ")\\b", "gm");
    $('div, p, span').each(function() {  // use your selector of choice here
        var html = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(html.replace(regExp, "<a href='#'>$1</a>"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Great answer. I like your way better. But how can I get it to work with more then the word "hashtag"? Such as, every word staring with the symbol '#'

Comment: something like var regExp = new RegExp("\\b(" + /#*/ + ")\\b", "gm");

Comment: Yes, you replace the `"hashtag"` part of `regExp` with a regular expression of your choice, e.g. `"#+"` or `"hashtag|special|another"`.

Comment: If I use this: b(" + "#" + ") it breaks! :O

Comment: Sorry, I just learned that a '#' is treated as a word boundary. To replace '#'s you will have to use `var regExp = new RegExp("(\\W)(#\\w*)(\\W)", "gm");` and as the second argument of the replace `"$1<a href='#'>$2</a>$3"`. The middle part of the RegExp (`(#\\w*)`) will match all words starting with '#' or the hashtag itself).

Comment: Acutally, I only used the `new RegExp(...)` format to allow a variable to be inserted in the middle. If you have a fixed regular expression you can write `var regExp = /(\W)(#\w*)(\W)/gm;` instead.

Comment: Can I exclude the has tag itself?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6957/discussion-between-julian-d-and-jackson-gariety)

Answer (score 2):

JS :

```
function replaceText() {
    $("*").each(function() {
        if($(this).children().length==0) {
           $(this).html($(this).text().replace('hashtag', '<span style="color: red;">hashtag</span>'));
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(replaceText);
$("html").ajaxStop(replaceText);
```

HTML :

```
<html>
<p>
The word hashtag is in this sentence.
</p>
</html>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zCxsY/

Source : [jQuery - Find and replace text, after body was loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349446/jquery-find-and-replace-text-after-body-was-loaded)

This is done with span but will work with  obviously

Comment: Sweet! That's way simpler then I thought. But how can I new replace "hashtag" with some variable. like...

var thetext = hashtag
that way I can change it...

.replace($thetext

Comment: Sweet! Now how could I go about selecting all words beginning with the # symbol?

Comment: Julian D.' answer is the way to go then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jQuery very much but I think you can't just say `.indexOf('hashtag')`, you have to iterate through the text itself. Let's say with substring. Probably there's an jQuery function that will do this for you, but that might be your problem for finding `'hashtag'`.

Comment: You should learn jQuery. It is more simpler and easier to use than the plain-old javascript. (I didn't *downvote*)

Comment: Never said that indexOf is jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The *clean* variant would be this:

```
$(function() {
    var searchTerm = 'hashtag';

    $('body *').contents()
    .filter(function () { 
        return this.nodeType == 3 
               && this.nodeValue.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1; 
    })
    .replaceWith(function () {
        var i, l, $dummy = $("<span>"),
            parts = this.nodeValue.split(searchTerm);

        for (i=0, l=parts.length; i<l; i++) {
            $dummy.append(document.createTextNode(parts[i]));
            if (i < l - 1) {
                $dummy.append( $("<a>", {href: "", text: searchTerm}) );
            }
        }
        return $dummy.contents();
    })
});
```

It splits the value of the text node at `searchTerm` and re-joins the parts as a sequence of either new text nodes or `<a>` elements. The nodes created this way replace the respective text node.

This way all text values keep their original meaning, which cannot be guaranteed when you call `replace()` on them and feed them to `.html()` (think of text that contains HTML special characters).

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/rGcxw/

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for another option. Any idea how I would select all words with a # symbol before item?

Comment: @Jackson That's quite a significant change in requirements. Maybe you should have made that part of your original question?

Comment: Yeah, here's that hindsight kicking in. I'll start a new question later.