# Wrapping a text on arbitrary non-whitespace characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have long namespaces to be displayed in my articles (like `MyProject\Sub\Level`) and I want them to be wrapped on a backslash character (`\`) if the window width is insufficient. How can I implement this using CSS or JS/jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To tell browsers that a line break is permitted after a character, insert the ZERO WIDTH SPACE (ZWSP) character, U+200B, after the character. In HTML markup, you can use the character reference `​', e.g.

```
MyProject\&#x200b;Sub\&#x200b;Level
```

If you add the characters via scripting, you can enter the character itself, using the string literal `\u200b`.

Some old browsers (IE 6) used to have problems with this, but now this approach seems to work better than the alternative, the old `<wbr>` tag (which was well-supported but has now been messed up in new versions of IE).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following css in the element that contains the text:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

It's a css3 property supported in modern browsers: Google Chrome 6, Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 3, Opera 10 y Safari 5.

***Acclaration***: It won't break on `/` character only, it could break on any character of the word according to the stretching of container.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the soft-hyphen (`&shy;`) around the `\` characters; the soft-hyphen allows a word to break at a given point, appearing *only* if the word does, in fact, break at that point.

It also doesn't appear in the text if it's copied and pasted (tested in Chromium 19/Ubuntu 11.04); this approach uses `replace()` and jQuery's `html()` method with the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>\some\text\possibly\a\path</li>
    <li>\another\path</li>
    <li>\something\else\also\quite\long</li>
</ul>​
```

And CSS:

```
li {
    width: 8em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}​
```

jQuery:

```
$('li').html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace(/(\\)/g, '&shy;$1&shy;')
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TffRf/).

Obviously, you don't need to use the soft-hyphen on *both* sides of the `\` character, that was just a demonstration for how it *might* be used.

An alternative, if you'd rather avoid the appearance of `-` characters at the break-point, is to use the same approach as above, but instead insert an empty `span` element, and give it the style `display: inline-block;`:

jQuery:

```
$('li').html(function(i, h) {
    return h.replace(/(\\)/g, '$1<span></span>')
});​
```

CSS:

```
li {
    width: 8em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
li span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TffRf/2/).

References:

- [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).
- [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably follow the example on [jQuery - Find and replace text, after body was loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349446/jquery-find-and-replace-text-after-body-was-loaded) and have it insert a break following every slash